# How can I modify Joomla article styles?

Tags: html, joomla, components, joomla2.5, joomla-article

I'm using Joomla 2.5.8 for my website. Now I want to style the articles of my Blog. Under the article div I want to add another div with an image to have a special effect. Is this possible?

This is the HTML from Joomla:

```
<div class="item column-1">
    <h2>Test 2</h2>
    <ul class="actions"></ul>
    <dl class="article-info"></dl>
    <p>Das ist der zweite Test-Beitrag!</p>
    <div class="item-separator"></div>
</div>
<div class="item column-2">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <ul class="actions"></ul>
    <dl class="article-info"></dl>
    <p>Das sind die Blog-Einträge</p>
    <div class="item-separator"></div>
</div>
```

And that's it how I imagine it:

```
<div class="item column-1">
    <h2>Test 2</h2>
    <ul class="actions"></ul>
    <dl class="article-info"></dl>
    <p>Das ist der zweite Test-Beitrag!</p>
    <div class="item-separator"></div>
</div>

<div class="myDiv"></div>

<div class="item column-2">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <ul class="actions"></ul>
    <dl class="article-info"></dl>
    <p>Das sind die Blog-Einträge</p>
    <div class="item-separator"></div>
</div>

<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please avoid customizing the core Joomla files.
Yes, you can customize like that by using the template overridden method. For more details go the link below:

[How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)